# Making a long IF / operator statement shorter

Tags: php

Can someone provide some tips for avoiding long operator statements like the one below... can NULL, '', and -1 be grouped together

```
if(($row['ios'] == null && $row['android'] == null)||
($row['ios'] == null && $row['android'] == -1) || 
($row['ios'] == null && $row['android'] == '') || 
($row['ios'] == '' && $row['android'] == null) || 
($row['ios'] == '' && $row['android'] == '') || 
($row['ios'] == '' && $row['android'] == '-1') || 
($row['ios'] == '-1' && $row['android'] == null) || 
($row['ios'] == '-1' && $row['android'] == '') || 
($row['ios'] == '-1' && $row['android'] == '-1')){
$desktop_count++;
}
```

Comment: `if(empty($row['ios']) && empty($row['android'])) { $desktop_count++; }` - [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) returns true if string is `""`, `0`, `0.0`, `"0"`, `null`, `false,` or `array()` - you may need an additional check for -1.

Comment: This looks like you are trying to somehow make sense of data that might contain anything and nothing... Often it makes more sense to cure the cause instead of the symptom...

Comment: Or at least wrap those comparison variants in a function, then use `is_nullish($ios) && is_nullish($android)`.

Comment: What is the value if it is true? Let's say it is an android, what is the value of the key?

Comment: I believe you can get a much better solution if you answer my question above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In_array is a better alternative.

```
if(in_array($row['ios'], [null, "", -1]) && in_array($row['android'], [null, "", -1])){
   $desktop_count++;
}
```

---

As Felippe below says it can be a benefit to use an variable.

```
$invalidValues = [null, "", -1];
if(in_array($row['ios'], $invalidValues) && in_array($row['android'], $invalidValues)){
       $desktop_count++;
}
```

Comment: I would use `$invalidValues = [null, "", -1];` Then there is no need to repeat the array. Good solution btw.

Comment: Same same. But yes if you need to change them in the future that is a better alternative.

Comment: That is probably true now that I think about it.

Comment: Thank you, I love how informative and smart everyone is on here. Never thought about using an `array`... nice and clean.

Comment: Don't forget about the other answer. In my opinion it's a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of [PHP's type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) to convert your variables into integers:

```
if( (int)$row['ios'] <= 0 && (int)$row['android'] <= 0 )
{
    $desktop_count++;
}
```

No mess, no fuss.

You *could* forgo the explicit `(int)` casting but using explicit casting helps to avoid ambiguity when you read this code at a later time.

For reference, below are the `var_dump()`s of the values which you are working with:

```
var_dump( (int)'' );
var_dump( (int)'-1' );
var_dump( (int)null );

int(0)
int(-1)
int(0)
```

Comment: This is much better than mine actually.